# If statements If and Else outcomes not working

Tags: python-3.x

```
if choice == 'E':
    num1 = random.randint(1,5)
    num2 = random.randint(1,5)
    print("what is " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2)+ "")
    time.sleep (1)
    answer = input("What is your answer?: ")
    qanswer = (num1 + num2)
    if answer == qanswer:
        print ("You got it right!")
    else:
        print ("You got it wrong...")
```

The problem here with my code is that though num1 + num2 = qanswer, when I make the if statement answer == qanswer, it always says I have gotten it wrong, feedback on question and code in general are appreciated, thankyou!

Comment: `input` takes an argument as an `string`, in your case you need to type cast `answer` variable to `int` as you're comparing it to an integer variable, here which is `qanswer`.

Answer (score 0):

The [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) command reads in a string, even if what you type happens to represent a number.

Convert the "answer" to an integer before attempting to compare the values:

```
answer = int(input("What is your answer?: "))
qanswer = (num1 + num2)

if answer == qanswer:
    print ("You got it right!")
else:
    print ("You got it wrong...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to type cast while taking value for `answer` because `input` command reads as a string. In your case you just compare `str` with `int`. According to your code-

```
print(type(answer)) 
print(type(qanswer))
```

Output :

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
```

try something following

```
import random
import time

choice = 'E'

if choice == 'E':
    num1 = random.randint(1,5)
    num2 = random.randint(1,5)
    print("what is " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2)+ "")
    time.sleep (1)
    answer = int(input("What is your answer?: "))
    qanswer = (num1 + num2)
    if answer == qanswer:
        print ("You got it right!")
    else:
        print ("You got it wrong...")
```

Comment: @Rexo if it helped you, please upvote the answer and marked tick as a correct answer.